# implementing save and new button not working

Tags: salesforce, extension-methods, visualforce

I am following this link to Create Save and New Functionality on page

[How to implement "Save & New" functionality in a VisualForce Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921414/how-to-implement-save-new-functionality-in-a-visualforce-page)

According to that i have did following

1.Create a apex class Opportunity and implement extension method

```
public with sharing class Opportunity
{
  ApexPages.standardController m_sc = null;

  public Opportunity(ApexPages.standardController sc)
  {
    m_sc = sc;
  }


  public Pagereference doSaveAndNew()
  {
    SObject so = m_sc.getRecord();
    upsert so;

    string s = '/' + ('' + so.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) + '/e?';
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.Info, s));
    return new Pagereference(s);
  }

  }
```

this compiles fine

2.create a new page , extend the controller ,create button and call method

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Opportunity" >
   <apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    {!Opportunity.Name}

    <apex:commandButton action="{!doSaveAndNew}" value="Save & New"/>
  </apex:form>
   </apex:page>
```

this gives me error "Unknown method 'OpportunityStandardController.doSaveAndNew()'"

I dont know what step I am missing in this process

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The APEX Class extension should not be the same with object name 
APEX Class Name

`OpportunityController`

APEX Page

`OpportunityPage`

The code should be

`<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityController" >`

I think maybe the class name equal the object standard name will error

Answer (score 0):

As Joseph pointed out, the page is trying to access the method in the standard controller 'OpportunityStandardController.doSaveAndNew()' and cannot find it since both the extension and the standard controller are called the same thing and it's just looking in the wrong class.

You probably just need to rename your controller extension to something else. I typically throw "Extension" on the end of the class name so I know what it is for. As an example, maybe something like "OpportunitySaveExtension". Then update your visualforce page to reference the renamed class in the "Extensions" attribute.

extensions="OpportunitySaveExtension"